# Why does sr1 in Scappy always return None?

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying  to create a three-way handshake with Scapy, but none of the ports seem to return anything, no matter what. No matter what happens, the response is always `None`.

```
for i in range(20, 1025):
    syn_segment = TCP(dport=i, seq=123, flags='S')
    my_packet = address / syn_segment
    response = sr1(my_packet, timeout=2, verbose=False)
    if not (response is None):
        if response[TCP].flags == 18:
            print(f'port {i} is open')
```

Comment: Have you checked `sr1` is using the correct interface? You may need to set it explicitly depending on your network setup `sr1([...], iface='<ENTER_INT_HERE>')`

Comment: Your snippet is incomplete. What's "address"?